# Send Emails to Wordpress Users on Post Publish and Update

Tags: wordpress, email, post

I have managed to send users an email when a post is published using transition_post_status, but it does not send when the post is updated. I have tried using 'new' with both old_status and new_status but no luck. Any direction is greatly appreciated. My reference thus far is from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100644/how-to-auto-send-email-when-publishing-a-custom-post-type?rq=1

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'send_media_emails', 10, 3);
function send_media_emails($new_status, $old_status, $post){
     if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status)
        return;

        $the_media = get_users( array ( 'role' => 'media' ) );
        $emails = array ();

        foreach($the_media as $media)
            $emails[] = $media->user_email;

        $body = sprintf('There are new bus cancellations or delays in Huron-Perth <%s>', get_permalink($post));

        wp_mail($emails, 'New Bus Cancellation or Delay', $body);

}
```

//Working but sending double emails now. I tried wrapping it all in the function but that didn't work either. just confused as to where to put it.

```
 function send_media_emails($post_id){

$the_media = get_users( array ( 'role' => 'media' ) );
$emails = array ();

if( ! ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id) && wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ) ) { 
        return;
    }
if(get_post_status($post_id) == 'draft' or get_post_status($post_id) == 'pending' or get_post_status($post_id) == 'trash'){
        return;
        }
foreach($the_media as $media){
        $emails = $media->user_email;
    }
    $body = sprintf('There are new bus cancellations or delays in Huron-Perth <%s>', get_permalink($post_id));

    wp_mail($emails, 'New Bus Cancellation or Delay', $body);   

}
add_action('post_updated', 'send_media_emails');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transition_post_status` hook only fires when the post status changes, e.g. from 'Draft' to 'Publish'.

A better hook would be [`post_updated`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated). This fires on all updates, so you'll need to filter out updates to drafts and comments in your script.

You *might* be able to do a ['publish_to_publish'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions#.7Bold_status.7D_to_.7Bnew_status.7D_Hook) action, but I haven't tested this personally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, cpilko, Using post_updated does work, and after I filter out for draft, and trash it works however it is sending 2 emails for every 1 it should be sending? not sure how to stop that now.

Comment: It's probably an issue with Autosave. Try adding a conditional for `! wp_is_post_autosave($post->ID)`. See [this article](https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-save_post-called-twice/) for more details.

Comment: I have added my updated code above. I am not sure where to use this as it is still sending twice. Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: Try this instead: `if(  wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) )  return;`. I think you want this to fire on a revision.

Comment: hmm no is still send 2 emails back to back

Comment: Ill mark your answer right since technically it was the original one asked an re-post my email problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: I just ran a test on one of my WP installs. I'm only getting one call from a `post_updated` action. You might want to check other plugins and code to make sure there isn't some sort of automatic edit taking place, either that or use the 3-variable syntax and only send a mail if `$post_after` is updated a certain amount of time after `$post_before`.

Answer (score 0):

transition_post_status will also fire when a post is updated (publish > publish for example).

However, a known bug makes transition_post_status sometimes fire twice: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/15094

There's a solution for the double firing of transition_post_status, which I copy from there:

```
function ghi15094_my_updater( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    // run your code but do NOT count on $_POST data being available here!
}

function ghi15094_transition_action( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) && REST_REQUEST ) { 
        ghi15094_my_updater( $new_status, $old_status, $post );
        set_transient( 'my_updater_flag', 'done', 10 );
    } else {
        if ( false === get_transient( 'my_updater_flag' ) ) {
            ghi15094_my_updater( $new_status, $old_status, $post );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'ghi15094_transition_action', 10, 3 );
```